# Максимальная сумма элементов массивов. Python

Tags: python, алгоритм, комбинаторика

У меня есть 3 массива:

```
p1 = [400,500,300]
p2 = [800,1000,600]
p3 = [600,750,450]
```

Мне нужно найти максимальную сумму элементов, не используя элементы из столбцов, которые были задействованы и начать подсчёт суммы с 1 массива.

Например варианты сумм для 1 элемента 1 массива(400): 400 + 1000 + 450 либо 400 + 600 + 750.

варианты сумм для 2 элемента 1 массива(500): 500 + 800 + 450 либо 500 + 600 + 600.

Варианты сумм для 3 элемента 1 массива(300): 300 + 1000 + 600 либо 300 + 800 + 450.

наибольшей суммой является 300+1000+600 = 1900

Comment: Что такое "лучший элемент"? Какого ребра?

Comment: РебрА графа, который можно использовать для решения через алгоритм Дейкстры. Лучший элемент - самый подходящий кандидат на нахождение максимальной суммы.

Comment: Граф определяется не только рёбрами, но и вершинами. Что здесь вершины? Что такое "самый подходящий кандидат на нахождение максимальной суммы"? В этом предложении вы даёте определение задачи, а не путь её решения

Comment: В вопросе написал ребро вместо вершины. А кандидат на нахождение максимальной суммы это выбранный элемент, для которого перебираются варианты.

Comment: Теперь непонятно, что является ребром в вашем графе :) А по определению лучшего элемента получаем: "Мне нужно найти максимальную сумму следующим образом: выбрать выбранный элемент, для которого перебираются варианты из 1,2,3 столбца.", что тоже непонятно. В общем, сделайте понятное и однозначное условие

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это [задача о назначениях.](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85)

Решается, например, [венгерским алгоритмом](https://e-maxx.ru/algo/assignment_hungary) (реализация с минимизацией)

[Здесь вариант](https://habr.com/ru/post/63982/) с максимальной прибылью